# Best way solving optimization with multiple variables in Matlab?

Tags: optimization, matlab, equation-solving, multiple-variable-return

I am trying to compute numerically the solutions for a system of many equations and variables (100+). I tried so far three things:

1. I now that the vector of p(i) (which contains most of the endogenous variables) is decreasing. Thus I gave simply some starting points, and then was increasing(decreasing) my guess when I saw that the specific p was too low(high). Of course this was always conditional on the other being fixed which is not the case. This should eventually work, but it is neither efficient, nor obvious that I reach a solution in finite time. It worked when reducing the system to 4-6 variables though.
2. I could create 100+ loops around each other and use bisection for each loop. This would eventually lead me to the solution, but take ages both to program (as I have no idea how to create n loops around each other without actually having to write the loops - which is also bad as I would like to increase/decrease the amount of variables easily) and to execute.
3. I was trying fminsearch, but as expected for that wast amount of variables - no way!

I would appreciate any ideas... Here is the code (this one the fminsearch I tried):

**This is the run file**:

```
clear all
clc

% parameter

z=1.2;
w=20;
lam=0.7;
tau=1;
N=1000;
t_min=1;
t_max=4;
M=6;
a_min=0.6;
a_max=0.8;

t=zeros(1,N);
alp=zeros(1,M);
p=zeros(1,M);
p_min=2;
p_max=1;

for i=1:N
t(i)= t_min + (i-1)*(t_max - t_min)/(N-1);
end

for i=1:M
alp(i)= a_min + (i-1)*(a_max - a_min)/(M-1);
p(i)= p_min + (i-1)*(p_max - p_min)/(M-1);
end

fun=@(p) david(p ,z,w,lam,tau,N,M,t,alp);

p0=p;

fminsearch(fun,p0)
```

**And this is the program-file**:

```
function crit=david(p, z,w,lam,tau,N,M,t,alp)

X = zeros(M,N);
pi = zeros(M,N);
C = zeros(1,N);
Xa=zeros(1,N);
Z=zeros(1,M);

    rl=0.01;
    rh=1.99;
      EXD=140;

      while (abs(EXD)>100)
          r1=rl + 0.5*(rh-rl);  
for i=1:M

for j=1:N

      X(i,j)=min(w*(1+lam), (alp(i) * p(i) / r1)^(1/(1-alp(i))) * t(j)^((z-alp(i))/(1-alp(i))));
      pi(i,j)=p(i) * t(j)^(z-alp(i)) * X(i,j)^(alp(i)) - r1*X(i,j);

end

end

        [C,I] = max(pi);

        Xa(1)=X(I(1),1);

         for j=2:N
    Xa(j)=X(I(j),j);
         end 

      EXD=sum(Xa)- N*w;
      if (abs(EXD)>100 && EXD>0)
          rl=r1;
      elseif (abs(EXD)>100 && EXD<0)
          rh=r1;
      end
      end

Ya=zeros(M,N);

for j=1:N    
Ya(I(j),j)=t(j)^(z-alp(I(j))) * X(I(j),j)^(alp(I(j)));
end

  Yi=sum(Ya,2);

  if (Yi(1)==0)
          Z(1)=-50;
  end

  for j=2:M
      if (Yi(j)==0)
         Z(j)=-50;
      else
      Z(j)=(p(1)/p(j))^tau - Yi(j)/Yi(1);
      end
  end

zz=sum(abs(Z))
crit=(sum(abs(Z)));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all my recommendation: use your brain.

What do you know about the function, can you use a gradient approach, linearize the problem, or perhaps fix most of the variables? If not, think twice before you decide that you are really interested in all 100 variables and perhaps simplify the problem.

---

Now, if that is not possible read this:

- If you found a way to quickly get a local optimum, you could simply wrap a loop around it to try different starting points and hope you will find a good optimum.
- If you really need to make lots of loops (and a variable amount) I suppose it can be done with recursion, but it is not easily explained.
- If you just quickly want to make a fixed number of loops inside each other this can easily be done in excel (hint: loop variables can be called t1,t2 ... )
- If you really need to evaluate a function at a lot of points, probably creating all the points first using `ndgrid` and then evaluating them all at once is preferable. (Needless to say this will not be a nice solution for 100 nontrivial variables)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comment. The problem is I cannot use a gradient approach (as the gradients depend on the solution to the whole problem), it is non-linear and I cannot fix variables. 
The ngrid is also not feasible, as I would then need to evaluate at all possible mappings of the other variables (N=1000). And this is a bit too much. I wrote now a loop for 8 variables, to see how long it takes. But my guess is long, and adding more variables increases time exponentially. What did you mean with the local optimum, I didn't grasp your strategy on that idea.

Comment: Well, perhaps you can fix N-5 variables, optimize the remaining 5 to get a local optimum, use this as a starting point, fix another N-5 variables optimize the remaining other 5 ... and repeat this a few hundred times. -- Unless your function has at least some nice properties you cannot expect a nice way to find a great solution.